# flutter: How to close a giffy dialog

Tags: flutter

How to close a [NetworkGiffyDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72693541)?

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => NetworkGiffyDialog(
    image: Image.asset('asset/gif/send.gif'),
    title: const Text('Send Money',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
    description:const Text('Are you sure you want to Send this Amount?',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.BOTTOM,
      onOkButtonPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Sent with Success");
      },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Navigator.push(...)`, just use `Navigator.pop(context, result)` on the `NetworkGiffyDialog.onOkButtonPressed` and/or `NetworkGiffyDialog.onCancelButtonPressed` events. Where the `result` can be a boolean that says if the user did tap on `Cancel` or `OK` button. It should close the dialog displayed by the [showDialog function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

just like onOkButtonPressed, add **onCancelButtonPressed** inside NetworkGifyDialog, also add **buttonCancelText** for text.

```
buttonCancelText: Text('cancel'),
//dismiss the dialog.
onCancelButtonPressed:()
{
Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

```
showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (_) => NetworkGiffyDialog(
                            key: keys[1],
                            image: Image.network(
                              "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shashank02051997/FancyGifDialog-Android/master/GIF's/gif14.gif",
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.TOP_LEFT,
                            title: Text(
                              'Granny Eating Chocolate',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            ),
                            description: Text(
                              'This is a granny eating chocolate dialog box. This library helps you easily create fancy giffy dialog.',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            onOkButtonPressed: () {},
//dismiss the dialog.
onCancelButtonPressed:()
{
Navigator.pop(context);
}
                          ));
                }),
```